# Get response from controller (spring mvc) asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have controller method that handles “Download ” button click on my page. This method makes call to our Service, where query is made.
My problem is that it takes around 20-30 sec for Service to execute the query before it will be returned to controller and put to outputStream to return back to user. So user is blocked and cannot do anything for this 30 sec until actual download start.

How can I resolve this issue? I don’t want my user wait. I am new to spring mvc and async programming. So please, explain me how can I do it asynchronously ?

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/download")
 public void downloadCSV(@RequestParam(“vendorId”), @RequestParam(“startDateString”),@RequestParam(“startDateString”),
   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
 {

List<Objects> listFromService = getListFromService();
 
  String fileName = vendorId + "_metrics.csv";
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+fileName);
  ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
 

  
  listFromService.stream().forEach(item -> {
   try {
    processListItem(item, outputStream);
   } catch (IOException e) {
   
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  });
  outputStream.flush();
 }
```

Comment: If you use jquery (ajax) on the client side then this can (by default) be called async

Comment: @ScaryWombat For now I do request through form submit(). So if I change it to ajax call, I will be able to do this asynchronous and user would not wait?

Comment: hint: the `a` of `ajax` stands for `asynchronous`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AJAX call from your view(JSP) to the controller as follows.

JSP Form:

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Download" ONCLICK="downloadCSV()">
</FORM>
```

Ajax functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadCSV() {
        console.log("Download called..");

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : '${home}/download',
            dataType : "json",
            crossDomain : true,
            success : function(data) {
                processResponse(data);
            },
            error : function(data) {

            }
        });
    }

    function processResponse() {
        console.log("Your response processing goes here..");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you call a function `processResponse()` from anonymous function of `success`, you can simply pass the `processResponse()` as value for `success` like this - `success : processResponse(data)`.

Comment: @VPK, yes also can. Thanks for the review.